# Specify specific language to translate website on image click

Tags: javascript, google-translate, bing-translator-api

I have two images on my website, lets say English and Korean. I want my webpage to be translated to Korean when the user clicks the Korean Flag and back to English when the user clicks England.

I would like probably a javascript function to be used on the onclick event of each image which would then call either Google Translate API or Microsoft Translate API and return the translated page.

I don't know if this is possible but if it is, I would really appreciate this. Adding the plugin directly though, is not an option available to me at this moment.

Thanks...

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: I've put bing translation widget on the page but this is not what would really like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging hard...I've come up with a solution with Bing Translate...

You can comment the alerts... And also 60000 here means an error will be displayed if translation is not completed in 60seconds...

```
<!-- The image showing korean -->
<img id="Koebtn" src="images/SP2.jpg">


<!-- The Code to translate -->
<script src="http://www.microsoftTranslator.com/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Koebtn").click(function(){

         if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
                Microsoft.Translator.Widget.Translate('en', 'es', onProgress, onError, onComplete, onRestoreOriginal, 60000);
            }

            //You can use Microsoft.Translator.Widget.GetLanguagesForTranslate to map the language code with the language name
        function onProgress(value) {
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.round(value);
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert("Translation Error: " + error);
        }

        function onComplete() {
            document.getElementById('counter').style.color = 'green';
        }
        //fires when the user clicks on the exit box of the floating widget
        function onRestoreOriginal() { 
            alert("The page was reverted to the original language. This message is not part of the widget.");
        }

      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I'll like a similar solution but with Google translate API... Anyone with the solution???